# TypeError: update_screen() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, type-error

Python Crash Course. Не могу понять из-за чего происходит ошибка.

**Ошибка:**
gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)
TypeError: update_screen() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

**файлы, связанные с этой ошибкой:**

*alien_invasion.py*

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Set the background color.
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    # Make a group to store bullets in.
    bullets = Group()
    #make an alien
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)

run_game()
```

*game_functions.py*

```
import sys

import pygame

from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)


def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet, if limit not reached yet."""
    # Create a new bullet, add to bullets group.
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen, each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    # Redraw all bullets, behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    alien.blitme()

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets, and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

*alien.py*

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien, and set its starting position."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        # Load the alien image, and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the alien at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Читайте текст ошибки. Там все написано предельно ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Функция update_screen из файла `game_functions.py`:

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
```

Заметим что она принимает 4 аргумента: `ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets`

Теперь рассмотрим предпоследнюю строчку файла `alien_invasion.py`:

```
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)
```

В ней вы передаёте этой функции 5 аргументов.

Это и вызывает ошибку.
Для того что бы функция принимало произвольное число аргументов используйте `*args`
Т.е перепишите функцию update_screen таким образом:

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, bullets, *args):
    """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen, each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    # Redraw all bullets, behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    for arg in args:
        arg.blitme()
```